# How to convert json data to html nested lists

Tags: algorithm

What is a good algorithm to convert this json data:

```
json_data = [
  {"text": "One", "indent": 0},
  {"text": "Two", "indent": 0},
  {"text": "Alpha", "indent": 1},
  {"text": "I", "indent": 2},
  {"text": "II", "indent": 2},
  {"text": "Three", "indent": 0}
]
```

To this html nested lists:

```
<ol>
    <li> One </li>
    <li> Two
        <ol>
            <li> Alpha
                <ol>
                    <li> I </li>
                    <li> II </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li> Three </li>
</ol>
```

Solutions in python or javascript would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through it on my own, here is a python solution

```
json_data = [
  {"text": "One", "indent": 0},
  {"text": "Two", "indent": 0},
  {"text": "Alpha", "indent": 1},
  {"text": "I", "indent": 2},
  {"text": "II", "indent": 3},
  {"text": "Three", "indent": 1}
]

for idx, data in enumerate(json_data):
    if idx == 0: 
        html = '<ol>'
        prev_indent = data['indent']
    if idx == len(json_data) - 1:
        html += '<li>%s</li>' % data['text']
        html += '</ol></li>' * data['indent']
        html += '</ol>'
        break

    next_indent = json_data[idx+1]['indent']
    indent = data['indent']
    if indent == next_indent:
        html += '<li>%s</li>' % data['text']
    elif indent < next_indent:
        html += '<li>%s<ol>' % data['text']
    else: # indent > next_indent
        html += ('<li>%s</li>' % data['text']) + ('</ol></li>' * (indent - next_indent))

    prev_indent = data['indent']

print(html)
```